# Fill button back-color from center towards corners and when leave a button to coming background-color from corners to center on button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have did until now created a button and give same property for button.
I have used  `linear-gradient` as the `background-image`
position the image at the center of the element and then transition
`background-size` from `0% 100%` to `100% 100%` on hover.
But I didn't do another animation when leave mouse over on button  background color coming from corners to center on button like `border-radius` in the center on button.

Below is my code:

```css
button {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 70px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: arial;
  background-color: #D5C264;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#000000, #000000);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transition: background-size .3s, color .3s;
}

.center-corner {
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}

.center-corner {
  background-size: 0% 0%;
}

button:hover {
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<button class='center-corner'>NEXT</button>
```

I want to create this effect exactly by UI/UX which I am sharing the link:
(this is button I am talking when hover change background color)

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Anyone help.

Comment: It's not exactly clear what effect you wanted, can you please elaborate or share an example link.

Comment: What is the picture of the button supposed to show us? What effect do you want to have on mouse-out? What's wrong with your current code? Please: read the "*[ask]*" guidance, and update your question with an [edit] so that we can understand what you want.

Comment: David Thomas thanks for reply me: I am trying to make same animated effect when hover on button. First of all I want when hover on button to expand background color black from center towards corners
I belive might I shoud use any transation property? Secondly When leave mouse hover on button background color coming from  towards corners in the center  like border-radius in the center on the button.

Comment: it is my code in html+css above, but  I should to create  exactly this effect  for button hover by the design UI/UX.
 You can click linke below: https://www.figma.com/proto/kwnH9NnM6eZO9eGAjEpEaG/Passport-Site-(Copy)?node-id=10%3A185&scaling=min-zoom&page-id=0%3A1&starting-point-node-id=10%3A185

Comment: David Thomas
 When click on button and leave mouse over on button I want to create this effecte by figma. Do you understend me?

Comment: Manas Khandelwal I should to create exactly this effect for button hover by the design UI/UX. You can click link. https://www.figma.com/proto/kwnH9NnM6eZO9eGAjEpEaG/Passport-Site-(Copy)?node-id=10%3A185&scaling=min-zoom&page-id=0%3A1&starting-point-node-id=10%3A185

Answer (score 0):

Use a div inside the button:

```css
button {
  cursor: pointer; /* now added in my edit */
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 70px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: arial;
  background-color: #D5C264;
  transition: color .8s;
  position: relative; /* now changed in my edit */
  z-index: 1; /* because text to be placed over the background */
  overflow: hidden; /* because background of div not to be overflow from button. */
}

.background {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* top-left and transform are for putting div in the middle of button.*/
  background-image: linear-gradient(#000000, #000000);
  transition: .8s;
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

button:hover {
  color: white;
}

button:hover .background {
  width: 150%;
  height: 500%; /* 150% and 500% because div completely to be fill the space of the button.*/
}
```

```html
<button class='center-corner'>
  <div class="background"></div>NEXT
  </button>
```

Comment: Arman Ebrahimi thanks a lot for your answer can explain me in details please.

Comment: @Ana you're welcome. this not was same that you wanted?

Comment: @Ana Since can't give background-image a border-radius, I made a div with position: absolute and border-radius: 50% and placed that in the center of the button. also for that text to be placed over the background, I have set z-index: 1; to button and z-index: -1; to div(.background). I am editing now my answer for more details and a small change.

Comment: Arman Ebrahimi
thanks for your answer is the right syntaxt if we use  tag div inside a  tag button? And when I Click on button we want background color display as circle and not as eclipse in the center on button.? Thanks

Comment: @Ana I don't think this has a problem, because not seem to make a problem in the program. Also for that background to be a circle instead of an ellipsis, you can increase height (for example to 500%) when hovering on the button. I am will edit now.